# Automatically shows a youtube video

Tags: video, youtube

I'm making a music website and I want to make a feature that automatically ads Youtube video next to my article. For example: If the article title is Pink Floyd than next to the article shows up first video from Youtube search results using keywords "Pink Floyd". I found this https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_partial but I'm not sure how to embed it on my page.. Can anyone help me

Answer (score 0):

This may help you:

```
<?php

$q = "Pink Floyd";

$feedURL = "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/videos/?q={$q}&orderby=relevance&max-results=1";
$sxml = simplexml_load_file($feedURL);

// get summary counts from opensearch: namespace
$counts = $sxml-> children('http://a9.com/-/spec/opensearchrss/1.0/');

 $total = $counts->totalResults;
 $startOffset = $counts->startIndex;
 $endOffset = ($startOffset-1) + $counts->itemsPerPage;

 // iterate over entries in resultset
 foreach ($sxml->entry as $entry) {
 // get nodes in media: namespace for media information
 $media = $entry->children('http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/');
 $title=$media->group->title;

// get video player URL
 $attrs = $media->group->player->attributes();
 $watch = $attrs['url'];

 $linkarr=explode('watch?v=',$watch);
 $linkarr1=explode('&',$linkarr[1]);
 $link="https://www.youtube.com/embed/".$linkarr1[0];

 // get video thumbnail
 $attrs = $media->group->thumbnail[0]->attributes();
 $thumbnail = $attrs['url'];

// get <yt:duration> node for video length
 $yt = $media->children('http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007');
 $attrs = $yt->duration->attributes();
 $length = $attrs['seconds'];

 if(($length - floor($length/60) * 60) <10){
 $time= floor($length/60). ':0'.($length - floor($length/60) * 60);
 }else{
 $time= floor($length/60). ':'.($length -floor($length/60) * 60);
 }

 // get <gd:rating> node for video ratings
 $gd = $entry->children('http://schemas.google.com/g/2005');
 if ($gd->rating) {
 $attrs = $gd->rating->attributes();
 $rating = $attrs['average'];
 } else {
 $rating = 0;
 }
 ?>
 <div style="float:left; margin:0px 10px 5px 20px; width:492px; height:100px; ">
 <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:100px; height:100px;">
 <img src="<? echo($thumbnail)?>" width="100" height="100" style="cursor:pointer;" onclick='changefunc("<? echo($link);?>")'>
 </div>
 <div style="float:left; position:relative; width:380px; height:auto; font-size:15px; margin-left:5px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">
 <a href="javascript:void(null)" onclick='changefunc("<? echo($link);?>")' style="color:#000;"><? echo($title);?></a>
 </div>

 <div style="float:left;width:380px; height:auto; font-size:12px; margin:25px 0 0 5px; font-weight:bold; color:#000;">
 Duration: <? echo($time);?>
 </div>
 </div>
 <?
 }?>
```